# Отличия хромированной и нержавеющей стали (или сталей)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Правильно ли, что нужно писать "сталей", т. к. имеются в виду два предмета?

Comment: Если два предмета, то каких? Предмет не может называться сталью.

Answer (score 2):

На выбор автора.

Если при имени существительном имеется несколько однородных определений, перечисляющих разновидности предметов, то определяемое существительное может стоять как в единственном, так и во множественном числе.

Единственное число подчеркивает внутреннюю связь определяемых предметов, например: существительное мужского и женского рода; глаголы первого и второго спряжения; в правой и левой половине дома и т. п.

В единственном числе ставится определяемое существительное, если между определениями стоит разделительный или противительный союз, например: печатное или литографированное издание; не французский, а немецкий язык.

Форма множественного числа определяемого существительного подчеркивает наличие нескольких предметов, например: немецкий и французский языки; филологический и исторический факультеты; старшая и младшая дочери и т. п.

Если определяемое существительное стоит впереди определений, то оно ставится в форме множественного числа, например: спряжения первое и второе; виды совершенный и несовершенный.

Answer (score 2):

Сталь — стали *(мн. спец.)* Твердый серебристо-белый металл, представляющий собою сплав железа (основа) с углеродом (до 1,7%) и другими примесями (металлами и металлоидами).
*Толковый словарь Ушакова*

Слово "стали" во множественном числе употребляется только как специальное в текстах научного содержания и стиля, обозначая разные виды стали. Ваше предложение как раз научного содержания, можно употребить "сталей" именно во множественном числе, подчеркнув это различие.

Но можно, конечно, использовать и единственное число. Я бы выбрала множественное.

Comment: По-моему, в той профессиональной среде, где сравнивают стали (мн.ч.), под сталью (ед.ч.) подразымевают марку стали (25Х1,5 Н3,5 /35Х12/ 30Х15 НГС/40Х15). Там говорят о хромированных (мн.ч.) сталях, но нет какой-то одной хромированной (ед.ч.) стали. Делаем вывод: неверно рассматривать этот текст под таким специальным углом зрения, как Вы предлагаете.

Answer (score 2):

**Отличия хромированной и нержавеющей  стали (или сталей).**

Предложение составлено некорректно.

1) В такой форме перечисляются **отличительные (характерные) свойства** данного вида стали, например:

Каковы отличительные  свойства хромированной  стали? Каковы отличительные свойства хромированной  и  нержавеющей **сталей?**.

2) Если надо **сравнить** два этих вида, то следует задавать вопросы **с предлогами:** В чем отличие **между** хромированной и  нержавеющей сталью?  Чем отличается хромированная сталь **от** нержавеющей? 
**Возможный ответ:** Хромированная сталь — это обычная сталь, на которую нанесено блестящее покрытие — хром, а нержавеющая — это сталь которая в своем составе содержит хром.

Answer (score 0):

Сравниваются не два предмета, а два вида стали. Поэтому я бы употребил единственное число. Аналогично: отличия пресной и соленой воды.

Answer (score 0):

Название материала как главную характеристику предметов или сред не употребляют во мн. числе, если для них оно общее. Небольшие различия, заложенные в определениях, не изменяют количества основных материалов.

В контексте оценки «сопоставимых» определений (ваш пример) уместно ед. число названия материала, не «сопоставимых» — мн. число: «Сравним углеродистые стали — отечественные и зарубежные».